CLI tool to monitor file size growth, transfer rate, and calculate progress bar/ETA?
I have a Proxmox job, and I'm running a backup job via the web UI. (I'm guessing it just uses the Proxmox vzdump command under the hood.) The final QEMU disk will be close to a TB in size, so I'd like a quick/easy way to monitor the speed, file size, and calculate a rough ETA.
I found there's "pv" (pipe viewer - https://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml), and also "progress" (https://github.com/Xfennec/progress).
However, "progress" seems to be designed to work only with cp/mv etc (i.e. coreutils commands), and pv needs to be inserted in the pipe somehow.
I did try tailing the file, and piping to pv, but that didn't seem to work - the transfer rate stays at 0 KB/s:
tail -f <filename> | pv > /dev/null

Is there an easy way to watch the size of a file grow over time, output some kind of nice progress bar, and possibly estimate the ETA (assuming you can pass in the final size of the file)?

Are you really going to sit and watch that? I mean, what business problem it is? In my case, Proxmox backups are run automatically, at night, with batch of VMs. Also, Proxmox VE is best used with their own Backup Server; in that case there is no "target file" to monitor backup, and the "spacial" progress doesn't correspond to the "temporal": for example, it may so happen that most blocks in the second part of the image are unchanged, so it finish the second part much more quickly. And you correctly state that you need to assume you know target size to calculate ETA, but you never know that.

You can do this relatively easily using tqdm. Something like this seems to do what you want, assuming that you know the expected size of the target file in advance:
# expected total file size in bytes
expected_total=100000

while :; do
  size=$(wc -c < /path/to/file)
  (( size >= expected_total )) && break
  echo "$size"
  sleep 0.5
done | tqdm --unit=bytes --update-to --total="$expected_total" --null

This will produce output like:

That gets you a progress bar and an estimated time to completion.
